# VSTS: Sharing Stories/Feature & Epic between Teams

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to share Epic/Feature/Stores between Team.
We have the Following Teams
1) PM, BA, DEV, Testing for most of the projects.
For a given userStory that might be tasks that are done by BA and only visible to them. But when their work is completed for that user Stories DEV team will pick up and create their own Task for that same user Story that BA team worked upon.
Similarly, when the Dev Task is completed Testing team will create other Task under that story.

How do i organize such a setup in VSTS so that I don't have to duplicate user stories/epic and features between team ?

Answer (score 0):

In VSTS, you probably want to define your own workflow stages, which will be the columns on the Kanban board view.  Your stages sounds something like Analysis, Dev, Test, etc.

This way, as each team member wants to progress the task, they will update the work item to the next work stage and likely reassign the task to a new team member.

See these articles for more details (which provide an example workflow very similar to yours):

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/kanban/add-columns
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/kanban/kanban-basics

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is that you can change work items’ area to the corresponding area of other team.

If you want to achieve other teams can see the related work items too, you can create a new area (e.g. SharedArea1) and assign to these teams. After that, you can change related work items’ area to that area (SharedArea1)

Team admin page (add another area):

[image]

This article may benefit you: [Multiple teams](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/scale/multiple-teams)